# MemoryStream to Base64 giving invalid Base64 string

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, base64

On a file upload I am converting the byte array to base64 before the database insert.  In the method below the Convert.ToBase64String() function is resulting in an invalid base64 string.  Should I be treating/validating the memory stream array before passing to the function?

```
using (var fileStream = file.OpenReadStream())
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
   fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
   fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
   string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
   fileIn.FileData = s;
 }
```

Comment: "giving invalid Base64 string" what you mean ?

Comment: If I copy and paste the Base64 string into a free online validator, it throws an error.  I am using the Base64 as an <img src="data: ...."/ > and the image is not rendering either.

Comment: Try `Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);`

Answer (score 1):

After copying, "rewind" MemoryStream to beginning:

```
fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
ms.Position = 0; //    <-- Add this line
fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
```